# docker images filter by name and wildcard

Tags: docker

Can you filter docker images by wildcards:

```
docker images "g*"
```

This actually works for some images starting with "g".

But it does not list `gcr.io/projectid`, do you know why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, it seems that if you want to use wildcards in `docker images`, you need to include the repository (and any subfolders) that are part of the full image name

Your image, above, does *not* start with a `g`, the docker registry does, so you get no hits.

So, for you `docker images "g*/*"` would list `gcr.io/projectid`

Not exactly helpful, maybe, but that's the reason that you don't get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity and reliability sake I'd recommend to always use:

`docker images | grep mysearchstring`

[This guy has a nice article on the wildcard](https://(This%20guy%20has%20a%20nice%20article%20on%20the%20wildcard)%5Bhttps://kliushnikov.medium.com/filtering-docker-images-5eb5aee358df%5D.%20It%20states%20that%20use%20of%20the%20wildcard). It states that the use of the wildcard doesn't cover the /. So if you've got an unknown level of / hierarchies you'd always have to create custom search strings. A simple text search via grep does the job nicely.